# How to compile with Sublime

Tags: compiling

I've followed the instructions on [here](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation), but I can't seem to compile.

The shortcut they have is C-l, but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: `C-l` means `control+L` on Windows and `command+L` on OS X. What do you want to compile? Do you mean building a LaTeX-File? Or compiling SublimeText from source?

Comment: @ralfix a latex file, but cmd+L doesn't work (I tried it), it simply highlights blocks of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Build a LaTeX-File, you have to use the `C-b`-Shortcut, which is `control+B` on windows and `command+B` on OS X. I suggest you to install the [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools)-Package trough the built-in package control, which provides amazing features for LaTeX editing and building.

To install LaTeXTools, press `control+shift+P` (`command+shift+P`), type `install`, accept with `enter` and then search for LaTeXTools.

The Build-Command of LaTeXTools uses `latexmk` (afaik), which is very good. I personally prefere `arara`, which needs to be added manually.